# How to display date in Calendar's week view?

Tags: theming, datetime

I'm using the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module. In the week display (not minicalendar), I would like to display the date ("January 21, 2015") in the heading in addition to the weekday ("Wednesday"), with the current date highlighted.

[image: Mockup of the header I want]

I've worked with `calendar-week-overlap.tpl.php`, I can see that the weekdays are written in a loop:

```
<?php foreach ($day_names as $cell): ?>
    <th class="<?php print $cell['class']; ?>" id="<?php print $cell['header_id']; ?>">
      <?php print $cell['data']; ?>
    </th>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The documentation at the top of this file refers to several promising looking variables: `$rows['date']`, `$rows['datebox'`,  `$min_date_formatted`, but if I try to use them inside this loop I get a PHP error stating that each of these variables does not exist!

`$cell['data']` contains the weekday only.

The documentation also refers to implementing my own `theme_preprocess_calendar_week_overlap` function, but I don't see where I can safely get and store the date for each day in this function.